# First subscriber not called with Redis MQ

Tags: redis, servicestack

I am using the solution from the ServiceStack Re-usability use case project.

To this solution I have added a new console app which contains the code below.

With the original Re-usability use-case project, when an EmailMessage is published it was handled by a subscriber which sent an email (i.e. SMessageService.Any(EmailMessage request).

When I run the console app, which means I have two applications that are subscribing to the EmailMessage, only the new console app receives the message.

I have the following:

My console app is:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var subscriberHost = new SubscriberHost();
        subscriberHost.Init();

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting of publishing 
                to happen on EmailMessage as we are subscribing to it...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class SubscriberHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    private RedisMqServer mqHost;

    public SubscriberHost() 
      :base("Subscriber console",typeof(EmailMessageEventHandler).Assembly)
    {

    }


    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        var redisFactory = new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379");
        mqHost = new RedisMqServer(redisFactory, retryCount:2);

        mqHost.RegisterHandler<EmailMessage>((message) =>
                           {
                                 var emailMessage = message.GetBody();
                                 Console.WriteLine(emailMessage.To);
                                 Console.WriteLine(emailMessage.Subject);
                                 Console.WriteLine(emailMessage.Body);
                                 return new SMessageReceipt {
                                           Type = "not used",
                                           To = "test",
                                           From = "Reusability",
                                           RefId = "1,"
                                   };
                                                                      });
   // mqHost.RegisterHandler<EmailMessage>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);
   mqHost.Start();
    }
}
```

I was expecting both subscribers to receive the EmailMessage but only the new console app is receiving it. Why isn't the other subscriber receiving the message?

The client code that does the publishing has not been modified.

Answer (score 1):

What I have shown above is using Redis MQ, and for the multiple subscribers problem I was testing I need the Redis Pub/Sub.

For MQ, a subscriber takes the message off the queue to process. Once processed, that is it.

For Pub/Sub, there could be many subscribers and each will receive a copy of the message.

I hope this helps others.